# How onClick is called always when the page is loaded? Error: Maximum update depth exceeded

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this code to get the user input and send it back to the dispatch

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

export default function Form(props) {
  const [book, setBook] = useState({
    title: '',
    author: '',
  });

  const onChange = (e) => {
    if (book[e.target.name] !== e.target.value) {
      setBook({
        ...book,
        [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
      });
    }
  };
  const { add } = props;
  return (
    <form>
      <input onChange={onChange} type="text" name="title" placeholder="Title" />
      <input onChange={onChange} type="text" name="author" placeholder="Author" />
      <button type="button" onClick={add(book.title, book.author)}>Add Book</button>
    </form>
  );
}
```

The add function is this:

```
  const submitBookToStore = (title, author) => {
    const newBook = {
      id: uuidv4(),
      title,
      author,
    };
    dispatch(addBook(newBook));
  };
```

Then I see this error:

```
Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.
```

The strange behaviour is it calls onClick when the page is loaded when I did not clicked!!

Comment: You're calling the function _immediately_ when you need to pass _a reference_ to the function to the `onClick` instead. `onClick={() => add(book.title, book.author)}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you call it like this:

```
onClick={add(book.title, book.author)}
```

It will run on render.
Try this instead:

```
onClick={() => add(book.title, book.author)}
```

That is because add() indicates a function call where as in your onChange, you are just giving a function to be called `onChange={onChange}` the difference lies in the parentheses `()`

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

export default function Form(props) {
  const { add } = props;
  const [book, setBook] = useState({
    title: '',
    author: '',
  });

  const onChange = (e) => {
    if (book[e.target.name] !== e.target.value) {
      setBook({
        ...book,
        [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
      });
    }
  };
  const handleAdd = () => { add(book.title, book.author) }
  return (
    <form>
      <input onChange={onChange} type="text" name="title" placeholder="Title" />
      <input onChange={onChange} type="text" name="author" placeholder="Author" />
      <button type="button" onClick={handleAdd}>Add Book</button>
    </form>
  );
}
```

Hopefully that helps